# Conda environment from environment.yml - private package from git?

Tags: python, github, conda, circleci

I use conda `environment.yml` for CircleCI continuous integration. It all works fine, but now I need to add a private package.

I install it from git via pip, but it can't access the page:

> Could not install requirement SE from
>   https://github.com/organisation/research.git#egg=SE because of error 404
>   Client Error: Not Found for url:
>   https://github.com/organisation/research Could not install requirement
>   SE from https://github.com/organisation/research.git#egg=SE because of
>   HTTP error 404 Client Error: Not Found for url:
>   https://github.com/organisation/research for URL
>   http://github.com/organisation/research.git#egg=SE

So I wonder, how can I pass / setup github credentials to/in the conda environment?

Just to be clear, this package dependency is happily tested on CircleCI by itself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, CircleCi offers to add your SSH key in project settings.